# Binding Kendo Grid to remote data MVC 4

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

When I am Binding Kendo Grid to remote data gives me back just plain text with data, but i want to return View with populated Grid. How can i return View with the data in Kendo Grid?

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix = "Id")] int categoryId,[DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var category = _db.Categories.Find(categoryId);

        var model =
             db.Query<Entry>()
                .OrderBy(en => en.Id)
                .Where(en => en.CategoryId == categoryId)
                .Select(en => new EntryViewModel
                {
                    Id = en.Id,
                    CategoryId = en.CategoryId,
                    Title = en.Title,
                    Username = en.Username,
                    Password = en.Password,
                    Url = en.Url,
                    Description = en.Description,
                }).AsEnumerable();

        return Json(model.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<PasswordCloudApp.ViewModels.EntryViewModel>


@(Html.Kendo().Grid<PasswordCloudApp.ViewModels.EntryViewModel>()
.Name("grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.Title);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Username).Width(100);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Password);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Url);
})
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Scrollable()
.Filterable()
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(20)
                    .Read(read => read.Action("Index", "Entry"))
 )
)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your code appears to look correct unless I'm missing something. It sounds like possibly a Kendo UI or JQuery script could be missing. Have you confirmed Kendo is successfully installed by using a date picker or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. It won't be exactly what you need, but the main point is to seperate the Index action and the one used to retrieve the grid data.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // Retrieve the viewmodel for the view here, depending on your data structure.
    return View(new EntryViewModel);
}

public ActionResult GetData(int categoryId, [DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var category = _db.Categories.Find(categoryId);
    var model = db.Query<Entry>()
        .OrderBy(en => en.Id)
        .Where(en => en.CategoryId == categoryId)
        .Select(en => new GridViewModel
        {
            Id = en.Id,
            CategoryId = en.CategoryId,
            Title = en.Title,
            Username = en.Username,
            Password = en.Password,
            Url = en.Url,
            Description = en.Description,
        }).AsEnumerable();

    return Json(model.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

@model IEnumerable<PasswordCloudApp.ViewModels.EntryViewModel>
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<PasswordCloudApp.ViewModels.GridViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Title);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Username).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Password);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Url);
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Filterable()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetData", "Entry", new { categoryId = Model.CategoryID })))
)
```